# Android: Default icon for current user location?

Tags: android, android-mapview

how do I get the default icon for the current user location to display it on the map? In the maps applications, it's a blue array... I'd like to have something like that, but I don't find it it android.R.drawable... How do I get this default user location icon?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Here](http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/) you can find the icons from Android 2.2, the current location icon is named `ic_maps_indicator_current_position`

Java Usage example: `myMenuItem.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_save);` 
Resource Usage example: `android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"`

Note from the link above:

> Some of the images in the Android jar are not public and therefore cannot be directly used (you can copy them to you own application, but can't reference them via the "android" package namespace). This project does *not* distinguish between what is public and what is not. If you try to use an image that is not public, you will get an error indicating that fact.

Comment: Recently I needed this as well, I found it under:
`android.R.drawable.ic_menu_mylocation`
`@android:drawable/ic_menu_mylocation`